# While trying to establish a connection between a database in python. I am getting" reviews table not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

con = sqlite3.connect('dbase.db') 

filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 5000""", con) 

def partition(x):

    if x < 3:
        return 0
    return 1
actualScore = filtered_data['Score']

positiveNegative = actualScore.map(partition) 

filtered_data['Score'] = positiveNegative

print("Number of data points in our data", filtered_data.shape)

filtered_data.head(3)
```

Comment: And your actual question is what exactly? First of all, the error message you've written in the title of the question doesn't match your posted code, second, you haven't explained what you're actually asking for help on here. Please update your question so that we can both replicate your problem entirely, and also with an actual question.

Comment: dbase.db is the database and I am trying to establish a connection. I have a "reviews" table, but yet when I am trying perform the above query I am getting "reviews table not found"

Comment: Please read the help-page ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to update your question following those guidelines.